# Searching JSON array with Javascript

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-table

I have a bootstrap table in which I return a list of employee details form my MongoDB. I want to make the table more user friendly, so I have added the Search feature as an add-on. It works very well, except when I have a an array as a value in my JSON data.

One of my JSON keys looks like this:

```
role:["Supervisor", "Manager"]
```

but most only have one value per key, including Supervisor and Manager.
IF I execute the search function from the table, looking for Manager, for example, I will show all the records with a role of Manager, except the ones that have a second role in the array as above.

Reading through the documents, it looks like I need to make a custom search function, and I assume, iterate through the array, but I'm lost on how to do it. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: did you search for "iterate through array javascript"?

Comment: Can you set up an example with your code?

Comment: Of course. All of the examples I looked at have something like var myArray = [a,b] and then they show how to loop through it. Mine is a little different, I think, as I'm getting back a JSON object from a database, that is loaded automatically into a table. It is not assigned to a variable, the table uses data-url to go get the data. Within that object is a single key of "role" that has (in some case, not all) an array of values. This is where I'm struggling

Comment: You should consider show more about your code !

Comment: @ErickLangfordXenes I'm not quite sure what the code should look like really. I'm assuming it will look like a 
function customSearch(text){
     for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
        if (this.data[i].role=="search.text"
           return data[i]
}

Javascript is new to me, so I may be on the completely wrong track.

Comment: I figured a way around it. I just created a role2 field. May not be the most elegant way, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I added a second field called "role2" which eliminated the array. This solved my issue.